# Variable not defined after including third party library in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, google-chrome-extension, computer-vision

I'm trying to add the posenet tensor flow model to a chrome extension. I copied the libraries from the example:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.7"></script>
<!-- Load Posenet -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet@0.1.2"></script>
```

to a folder called "tensorflow" in my extension's directory.
I imported the scripts from local in my background.html file

```html
 <html>
    <video autoplay="true" id="webcamVideo" width="227" height="227"></video>
    <script src="third_party/deeplearnjs/deeplearn.0.5.js"></script>
    <script src="third_party/deeplearnjs/deeplearn_knn_image_classifier.0.4.2.js"> </script>
    <script src="third_party/@tensorflow/tensorflow.js"></script>
    <script src="third_party/@tensorflow-models/posenet.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
    </html>
```

This seems to have no errors and I can successfully use objects from the deeplearn libraries in background.js. But when I try to use posenet in background.js, I get the error that posenet is not defined.

```
posenet.load().then(function(net){
  return net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, imageScaleFactor, flipHorizontal, outputStride)
}).then(function(pose){
  console.log(pose);
})
```

I've used posenet in React successfuly but I'm struggling to get it to work in this extension. Am I missing something in this workflow?

Comment: Maybe one of the preceding scripts defines a global `exports` or `module` or `define.amd`, in which case posenet will use it.

Comment: @wOxxOm can you elaborate please? What is the consequence of what your are suggesting?

Comment: I still didn't fully understand what you are suggesting, but to simplify I deleted the other scripts from background.html and deleted the dependence on those scripts in background.js. Now I just have the two tensorflow script tags in background.html and I still see "posenet is not defined"

Comment: It's worth noting that I'm following the posenet example where they have the two scripts as i do then use posenet in a third script tag. So i don't think the scripts are interrupting each other.
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet
Thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the dependency of tensorflow in posenet required the tensorflow library to be @tensorflow/tfjs so I just renamed the file to tfjs.js and it worked.